# how to customize the redirection flow after the enterprise is created through Android Management API?

Tags: android-management-api

I am currently working on an MDM (Mobile Device Management) Application that utilizes the Android Management API. I have successfully enrolled my devices Now, I need to know if there is a way that once the enterprise is created, the users can be directly redirected to the MDM (Mobile Device Management) webpage every time they access the API. How can I achieve this functionality?

Every time I had a routine of doing those things:

```
1.Signupurl to Google cloud,
2.Google ouath,
3.Enterprise organisation creating
4.Create policy
5.Device enrollement
```

If you could kindly guide me on how to customize the redirection flow after the enterprise is created through own hosting webpage in Android Management API or provide any relevant code examples, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this, you will need to create a console of your own. During enterprise sign-up flow where the enterprise admin can sign up with a Gmail account that’s not already associated with an enterprise. You need to create a specific web page that will handle for your callback URL:

Example:

```
CALLBACK_URL = 'https://my-mdm-console/enterprise_signup_callback.html'


# Generate a signup URL where the enterprise admin can signup with a Gmail
# account.
signup_url = androidmanagement.signupUrls().create(
    projectId=cloud_project_id,
    callbackUrl=CALLBACK_URL
).execute()
```

The callback URL that the admin will be redirected to after successfully creating an enterprise.

Before redirecting there, the system will add a query parameter to this URL named `/enterprise_signup_callback.html?enterpriseToken=xxxx`  which will contain an opaque token to be used for the [create enterprise](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises/create) request. The URL will be parsed then reformatted in order to add the **enterpriseToken** parameter, so there may be some minor formatting changes.

To complete the creation of the enterprise, you will need to retrieve the name of the [SignupUrl](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/signupUrls#SignupUrl) used to sign up for the enterprise  and **enterpriseToken** appended to the callback URL to create the enterprise name.

```
# Complete the creation of the enterprise and retrieve the enterprise name.
enterprise = androidmanagement.enterprises().create(
    projectId=cloud_project_id,
    signupUrlName=signup_url['name'],
    enterpriseToken=enterprise_token,
    body={}
).execute()
```

If you are building a server-based solution, you can create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/android/management/service-account) so you don’t need to authorize the access every time.

Additionally, I suggest reviewing the process of creating a [Customer-managed Enterprise](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise#customer-managed_enterprises) by having the Enterprise IT admin complete the sign-up flow, as this is the preferred method.